# Name of a map coupled with the identity

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, functions, map-projections

Given a map $\tau:\Omega\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, is there a standard name for the map $\tilde{\tau}:\Omega\longrightarrow\Omega\times\mathbb{R}$ that maps $\omega$ to $(\omega,\tau(\omega))$? It is somewhat useful in Probability, but I do not know of any standard terminology nor if there is some standard way to construct it besides just defining it as such. Thank you for any knowledge you might be able to share.

Comment: I believe some people call it the 'graph map' (because it is the natural map from $\Omega$ to the graph of $\tau$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People call it the 'graph' map, because it is the natural map from $\Omega$ to the graph of $\tau$. It can be constructed using the universal property of products: consider the maps $id_\Omega: \Omega \to \Omega$ (the identity map) and $\tau: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$. Then $\tilde{\tau}$ is the unique map $\Omega \to \Omega \times \mathbb{R}$ such that $p \circ \tilde{\tau} = id_\Omega$ and $q \circ \tilde{\tau} = \tau$, where $p: \Omega \times \mathbb{R} \to \Omega$ is the first projection and $q: \Omega \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is the second projection, satisfying the universal property of products (that is "terminal" with this property). It can be defined in any category with products.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing!

Comment: would you call 'graph map' also this similar construction?: given $\pi:\Omega\times \mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\tilde{\pi}$ sends $(\omega,n)$ into $(\omega, \pi(\omega,n))$. Essentially it is the same thing, but one component is forgotten in the identity part.

Comment: yes, just take $\Omega$ in the first definition to be $\Omega \times \mathbb{R}$

Comment: but this is not the case, one would have $((\omega,n), \pi(\omega,n))$ instead

Comment: I think it is the composition of the diagonal map $\Delta:X\longrightarrow X\times X$ (sends $x$ to $(x,x)$) with the product map of the projection on the first factor and $\pi$. So $\Delta:\Omega\times \mathbb{R}\longrightarrow (\Omega\times \mathbb{R})\times(\Omega\times \mathbb{R})$ and then $proj_1\times\pi:(\Omega\times \mathbb{R})\times(\Omega\times \mathbb{R})\longrightarrow \Omega\times\mathbb{R}$ which overall sends $(\omega,n)$ into $((\omega,n),(\omega,n))$ and then to $(\omega, \pi(\omega,n))$. Perhaps this modification of the graph map has no name.... I found it useful at times